# Pointing to a child route in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This looks like a big question but it's actually quite simple (I think), I want to point to a child view from my menu. In my top app component (`core`) I've defined a parent route named `Videos`, which have 3 child routes (`create`, `edit`, `list`) which it can render.

What I don't understand though is how to point to the child routes from my menu? Now I just point to the parent route but it doesn't know which child route to render since I'm not telling it how to do this.

How do you do this?

**core.component.ts** (the main app component):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
import {NavComponent} from '../nav/nav.component';
import {TagsComponent} from '../tags/tags.component';
import {VideosComponent} from '../videos/videos.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'core-app',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/core/core.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/assets/scripts/modules/core/core.component.css'],
  directives: [NavComponent]
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/videos/...', name: 'Videos', component: VideosComponent}
])

export class CoreComponent {

}
```

**videos.component.ts** (parent route):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
import {CreateVideosComponent} from '../videos/create/create.videos.component';
import {EditVideosComponent} from '../videos/edit/edit.videos.component';
import {ListVideosComponent} from '../videos/list/list.videos.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'videos',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/videos/videos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/assets/scripts/modules/videos/videos.component.css']
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/create', name: 'Create', component: CreateVideosComponent},
  {path: '/edit', name: 'Edit', component: EditVideosComponent},
  {path: '/list', name: 'List', component: ListVideosComponent}
])

export class VideosComponent {}
```

**list.videos.component.ts** (one of the child routes):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'list-videos',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/videos/list/list.videos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/assets/scripts/modules/videos/list/list.videos.component.css']
})

export class ListVideosComponent {}
```

**nav.component.ts** (my menu):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {NavService} from '../nav/nav-api.service';
import {NAVLIST} from '../nav/nav-list';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-list',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/nav/nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/assets/scripts/modules/nav/nav.component.css'],
  providers: [NavService],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  host: {
    '(mouseenter)': 'show()',
    '(mouseleave)': 'hide()'
  }
})

export class NavComponent {
  public isToggled = false;
  public links = NAVLIST;

  constructor(private _navService: NavService) {}

  show() {
    this.isToggled = this._navService.show();
  }

  hide() {
    this.isToggled = this._navService.hide();
  }
}
```

**nav.item.ts** (the interface for a menu item):

```
export interface NavItem {
  href: string,
  label: string,
  icon: string
}
```

**nav.list.ts** (the info for the menu):

```
import {NavItem} from '../nav/nav-item';

export var NAVLIST: NavItem[] = [
  { 'href': 'Videos', 'label': 'Videos', 'icon': 'icon icon-contact' }
]
```

**nav.component.html** (how I take `NAVLIST` and creates a menu from it):

```
<nav class="nav-wrapper" [class.is-toggled]="isToggled" [class.is-hidden]="!isToggled">
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li class="nav-link" *ngFor="#link of links">
      <a [routerLink]="[link.href]">
        <div class="label-wrapper">{{link.label}}</div>
        <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="{{link.icon}}"></i></div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage is something like this:

`<a [routerLink]="['ParentRouteName','ChildRoute','GrandchildRoute']">Somewhere</a>`

So in your example you can do something like:

`{ 'href': ['Videos','List'], 'label': 'Videos', 'icon': 'icon icon-contact' }`

and

`<a [routerLink]="link.href">`

Comment: Ye I've tried that but my nav.list.ts throws an error because it's the wrong type in my interface but I don't understand how to make a type an array.. Do you know?

Comment: `propertyName:propertyType`, so `href: string[]` or I believe `href: Array<string>` works too.

Comment: href: string[]  did the trick while replacing routerLink like you said, thanks! :)